# Jquery file upload new version (6.11) not working intermittently for IE 10 (multiple file upload)

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I tried the new version of Jquery File Upload from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload (6.11). I have implemented .ashx handler in ASP.Net as given in code https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki with new version of jquery file upload js files. The code works perfect with FF, Chrome. As per the wiki, the new version has added support for multiple file selection and drag drop for IE 10. The problem I am facing is, its not working properly for IE 10.

If I try to upload multiple files at once, few of the requests goes in pending state forever. and the component sends empty requests without any file (httpContext.Request.Current.PostedFiles.Copunt gives 0 for few requests, when trying to upload multiple files). This is happening only for IE10 and not with FireFox or Chrome.